# How can I move this zigzag border to the left side instead of the bottom?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a zig zag border on the bottom of my element. How can I move it to the border of the left side, instead?

```css
.zigzag {
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #e8117f 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(135deg, #e8117f 5px, #fff 0) 0 5px;
    background-color: #e8117f;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zigzag"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: What methods have you tried to get it on the left side?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to change the linear-gradient degrees to achieve this, **and** set `background-repeat` to `repeat-y`.

```css
  .zigzag {
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(-137deg, #e8117f 6px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(320deg, #e8117f 5px, #fff 0) 0 5px;
    background-color: #e8117f;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 10px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="zigzag"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made [an online generator](https://css-generators.com/custom-borders/) where you can easily get all the directions. It uses mask so it can work with any element and background coloration.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
}
.top {
  --mask: conic-gradient(from 135deg at top,#0000,#000 1deg 89deg,#0000 90deg) 50%/30px 100%;
}
.bottom {
  --mask: conic-gradient(from -45deg at bottom,#0000,#000 1deg 89deg,#0000 90deg) 50%/30px 100%;
}
.left {
  --mask: conic-gradient(from 45deg at left,#0000,#000 1deg 89deg,#0000 90deg) 50%/100% 30px;
}
.right {
  --mask: conic-gradient(from -135deg at right,#0000,#000 1deg 89deg,#0000 90deg) 50%/100% 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box top"></div>
<div class="box bottom"></div>
<div class="box left"></div>
<div class="box right"></div>
```