# Container with zigzag border at bottom only apply to the border

Tags: html, css, frontend

I trying to make a container which have zigzag border at bottom like below :

[image]

I tried this but I don't know how get raid of that bottom gray background, I only want the border to be gray like the image, anyone can help on this? :

https://jsfiddle.net/umw8yh21/1/

HTML :

```
<div class="myform">
   <div class="myformMain">Content</div>
   <div class="myformFooter"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.myform{
      border: 4px solid lightgrey;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.myformMain {
  height: 200px;
    padding: 36px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
}
.myformFooter:after{
content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    background: linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #d9d9d9 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #d9d9d9 -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #d9d9d9 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 0px 47%, 14px 41px, 14px 42px
}
```

EDIT : Other similar answer is not exactlly what I looking for, I already checked them, I need a way to make the border with same size to be in zigzag shape, not using any svg/png or texture for it, only css.

Comment: @SumitRidhal Yes I already checked that, my issue is how make the border to be zigzag not just fill the background with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Zigzag Border with a Textured Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031328/css-zigzag-border-with-a-textured-background)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zigzag border in css left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322690/zigzag-border-in-css-left-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SVG` as a bottom-repeated background with the `non-scaling-stroke` property set

```css
    div {
      width: 50%;
      height: 180px;
      border: 4px #ededed solid;
      border-bottom: 0;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg viewBox="0 0 200 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M -15 110 L100 10 L215 110" fill="none" stroke="%23ededed" stroke-width="4" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></svg>');
      background-position: bottom left;
      background-size: 10% auto;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Just pick the same value for both the border width and the `stroke-width` attribute of the `path`.

If you need to fill this element with text remember to add some room at the bottom (e.g. using a `padding-bottom`) so the content doesn't overlap the line.

Also it's worth noting that the attribute `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`will prevent the path to scale so you could seamlessly apply this background even to a responsive element (otherwise the normal border would keep the fixed width, while the `SVG` path would scale) e.g.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqyXje)

### [image]

Furthermore if you wish you could also change the amount of zizag by changing the `background-size` at some given mediaquery, e.g.

```
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  /* 12 background repetitions */
  div { background-size: calc(100% / 12) auto }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* 18 background repetitions */
  div { background-size: calc(100% / 18) auto }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```css
.container {
  height:150px;
  width:320px;
  border:3px solid grey;
  border-bottom:none;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg,transparent 50%,grey 50%,grey calc(50% + 3px),transparent 0) -13px 100%,
    linear-gradient(45deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%,grey calc(50% + 3px),transparent 0) 6px 100%;
  background-size:40px 20px;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```