# Vertical Zigzag boder on left and right of body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make some CSS code so that I can have vertical zigzag lines on the left and right of my BODY tag.

I want it to look like a ticket... something like this going from top to the bottom of the page on the left and right: https://roalddahl.fandom.com/wiki/Golden_Ticket?file=Golden_Ticket.png

I found this question with the requirement of the zigzags on the left, but it's not working correctly for me when I use on on the BODY: [zigzag border in css left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322690/zigzag-border-in-css-left-side)

```css
body {
  background-color: #c5ac5a;
  background: linear-gradient(-137deg, #c5ac5a 6px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(320deg, #c5ac5a 5px, #fff 0) 0 5px;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size:10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>The Title</h1>
</body>
```

EDIT: I want the whole background to be #c5ac5a and the vertical zigzags on both sides.

Comment: `when I use on on the BODY` --> where? we don't see this ..

Comment: @jsnoob don't link to jsfiddle and certainly not in comments. What is jsfiddle would stop, the question wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:before` and `:after` to achieve your goal. (I also changed the columns to use flex, but that's not necessary for the issue at hand). See provided snippet below:

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.ticket {
  background-color: #c5ac5a;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ticket:before,
.ticket:after {
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c5ac5a;
  background: linear-gradient(-137deg, #c5ac5a 6px, transparent 0) 0 5px, linear-gradient(320deg, #c5ac5a 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size:10px 10px;
}

.ticket:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.hr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Times, serif;
  font-size:40px;
}

.column {
  text-align:center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.ticket__footer {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket">
    <div class="hr">
    </div>
  <div class="title">
  <h1>
  GOLDEN TICKET
  </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="hr">
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <span class="small">DATE</span></br>
    <span class="bold">FEB. 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="small">TIME</span></br>
    <span class="bold">10 A.M (SHARP)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="small">PLACE</span></br>
    <span class="bold">RIGHT HERE</span>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hr">
  </div>

  <div class="ticket__footer">
  THIS GOLDEN TICKET ENSURES ADMITTANCE
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How would you go about increasing the size of the zigzag?